# Bash to find count of multiple strings in a large file

Tags: bash, unix, search

I'm trying to get the count of various strings in a large txt file using bash commands.

I.e. find the count of the strings 'pig', 'horse', and 'cat' using bash, and get an output say 'pig: 7, horse: 3, cat: 5'. I would like a way to search through the txt file only once, because it is very large (so I do not want to search for 'pig' through the whole txt file, then go back and search for 'horse', etc.)

Any help with commands would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: What if it is horses,pigs,or catt etc. Do you want to only count exact matches

Comment: Yes I want to only count exact matches, so 'horses' would not work, however 'Horse' would be fine, or 'hOrse' would be okay

Answer (score 9):

```
grep -Eo 'pig|horse|cat' txt.file | sort | uniq -c | awk '{print $2": "$1}'
```

Breaking that into pieces:

```
grep -Eo 'pig|horse|cat'  Print all the occurrences (-o) of the
                          extended (-e) regex 
sort                      Sort the resulting words
uniq -c                   Output unique values (of sorted input)
                          with the count (-c) of each value
awk '{print $2": "$1}'    For each line, print the second field (the word)
                          then a colon and a space, and then the first
                          field (the count).
```

Comment: Sorry I have a followup question. What if you want to only find say 'pig' but not 'piglet' i.e. you want only the specific string but not a string that has the specific string in it so we count 'horse' but not 'horse-pies', 'pig' but not 'piglet', etc.

Comment: But just to clarify, it's not case sensitive so 'Horse' would be counted

Comment: @ksung: add the options `-w` (only match words) and `-i` (case-insensitive) to the `grep`, making it `grep -Eiwo '....'`. (That will still match `horse-pies`, although not `piglet`, because hyphen is not a word character.)