# Saving values in BASH shell variables while using |tee

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh

I am trying to count the number of line matches in a very LARGE file and store them in variables using only the BASH shell commands.

Currently, i am scanning the results of a very large file *twice* and using a separate grep statement each time, like so:

```
$ cat test.txt 
first example line one
first example line two
first example line three
second example line one
second example line two
$ FIRST=$( cat test.txt | grep 'first example'  | wc --lines ; ) ;  ## first run
$ SECOND=$(cat test.txt | grep 'second example' | wc --lines ; ) ;  ## second run
```

and I end up with this:

```
$ echo $FIRST
3
$ echo $SECOND
2
```

Hopefully, I want to only scan the large file just once.  And I have never used *Awk* and would rather not use that!

The `|tee` option is new to me.  It seems that passing the results into two separate grep statements may mean that we only have to scan the large file once.

Ideally, I would also like to be able to do this without having to create any temporary files & subsequently having to remember to delete them.

I have tried multiple ways using something like these below:

```
FIRST=''; SECOND='';
cat  test.txt                                                   \
    |tee  >(FIRST=$( grep 'first example'  | wc --lines ;);)    \
          >(SECOND=$(grep 'second example' | wc --lines ;);)    \
          >/dev/null        ;
```

and using `read`:

```
FIRST=''; SECOND='';
cat  test.txt                                                       \
   |tee  >(grep 'first example'   | wc --lines | (read FIRST);  );  \
         >(grep 'second example'  | wc --lines | (read SECOND); );  \
         > /dev/null                   ;



cat  test.txt                                                           \
      | tee  <( read FIRST  < <(grep 'first example'  | wc --lines ))   \
             <( read SECOND < <(grep 'sedond example' | wc --lines ))   \
             >    /dev/null             ;
```

and with curly brackets:

```
FIRST=''; SECOND='';
cat test.txt                                                     \
  |tee   >(FIRST={$( grep 'first example'  | wc --lines ;)} )    \
         >(SECOND={$(grep 'second example' | wc --lines ;)} )    \
         >/dev/null                           ;
```

but none of these allow me to save the line count into variables ***FIRST*** and ***SECOND***.

Is this even possible to do?

Comment: "$( cat test.txt | grep 'first example'  | wc --lines ; ) "
you don't need cat, just "grep 'first example' test.txt" and you will avoid extra process

Comment: You will find an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28145077/bash-to-find-count-of-multiple-strings-in-a-large-file).

Comment: why the aversion to using `awk`? with one relatively simple `awk` script you can replace all of your current code **and** only scan the file once

Comment: The `>(command)` process substitution runs the command in a subshell. A variable you set in a subshell will not persist into the parent shell that's running the script. Sorry, this approach cannot work as you hope.

Comment: @edwardsmarkf : `tee` is not an _option_, it is an executable command - see _man tee_.

Comment: @edwardsmarkf : I don't quite understand what you want to achieve: Which information exactly would you like to have saved for later use? The output of the `grep` **and** the number of lines in that output?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`tee` isn't saving any work. Each `grep` is still going to do a full scan of the file. Either way you've got three passes through the file: two `grep`s and one [Useless Use of Cat](https://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html). In fact `tee` actually just adds a fourth program that loops over the whole file.

The various `| tee` invocations you tried don't work because of one fatal flaw: [variable assignments don't work in pipelines](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9954/why-is-my-variable-local-in-one-while-read-loop-but-not-in-another-seemingly). That is to say, they "work" insofar as a variable is assigned a value, it's just the value is almost immediately lost. Why? Because the variable is in a subshell, not the parent shell.

Every command in a `|` pipeline executes in a different process and it's a fundamental fact of Linux systems that processes are isolated from each other and don't share variable assignments.

As a rule of thumb, you can write `variable=$(foo | bar | baz)` where the variable is on the outside. No problem. But don't try `foo | variable=$(bar) | baz` where it's on the inside. It won't work and you'll be sad.

But don't lose hope! There are plenty of ways to skin this cat. Let's go through a few of them.

#### Two greps

Getting rid of `cat` yields:

```sh
first=$(grep 'first example' test.txt | wc -l)
second=$(grep 'second example' test.txt | wc -l)
```

This is actually pretty good and will usually be fast enough. Linux maintains a large page cache in RAM. Any time you read a file Linux stores the contents in memory. Reading a file multiple times will usually hit the cache and not the disk, which is super fast. Even multi-GB files will comfortably fit into modern computers' RAM, particularly if you're doing the reads back-to-back while the cached pages are still fresh.

#### One grep

You could improve this by using a single `grep` call that searches for both strings. It could work if you don't actually need the individual counts but just want the total:

```sh
total=$(grep -e 'first example' -e 'second example' test.txt | wc -l)
```

Or if there are very few lines that match, you could use it to filter down the large file into a small set of matching lines, and then use the original greps to pull out the separate counts:

```sh
matches=$(grep -e 'first example' -e 'second example' test.txt)
first=$(grep 'first example' <<< "$matches" | wc -l)
second=$(grep 'second example' <<< "$matches" | wc -l)
```

#### Pure bash

You could also build a Bash-only solution that does a single pass and invokes no external programs. Forking processes is slow, so using only built-in commands like `read` and `[[` can offer a nice speedup.

First, let's start with a [`while read` loop](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/209123/understanding-ifs-read-r-line) to process the file line by line:

```sh
while IFS= read -r line; do
   ...
done < test.txt
```

You can count matches by using double square brackets `[[` and string equality `==`, which accepts `*` wildcards:

```sh
first=0
second=0

while IFS= read -r line; do
    [[ $line == *'first example'* ]] && ((++first))
    [[ $line == *'second example'* ]] && ((++second))
done < test.txt

echo "$first"   ## should display 3
echo "$second"  ## should display 2
```

#### Another language

If none of these are fast enough then you should consider using a "real" programming language like Python, Perl, or, really, whatever you are comfortable with. Bash is not a speed demon. I love it, and it's really underappreciated, but even I'll admit that high-performance data munging is [not its wheelhouse](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice).

Comment: very interesting.  should the wildcards look like this?  `'*first example*'` with asterisk inside the quotes?

Comment: I know, it looks funny. If they're quoted then they are literal asterisks. They need to be unquoted to be treated as wildcards.

Comment: "I know, it looks funny. " - i can say that about the entire OS.
"Two of the most famous products of Berkeley are LSD and Unix. I don’t think that is a coincidence.”

Comment: one last dumb question - what happens if instead of reading directly from `test.txt` i actually wanted to use the results from another command such as `find` ?  i tried changing:   
```done < $(cat test.txt;)``` but got an "ambiguous redirect" error.

Comment: Use [process substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Process-Substitution.html): `done < <(cat test.txt)`

Comment: ha!  i had just researched this & found the same solution you graciously provided me with!  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16854280/a-variable-modified-inside-a-while-loop-is-not-remembered  THANK YOU SO MUCH John K.  i see why you have earned every one of your 65 well deserved gold badges.

Answer (score 3):

If you're going to be doing things like this, I'd really recommend getting familiar with `awk`; it's not scary, and IMO it's much easier to do complex things like this with it vs. the weird pipefitting you're looking at. Here's a simple `awk` program that'll count occurrences of both patterns at once:

```
awk '/first example/ {first++}; /second example/ {second++}; END {print first, second}' test.txt
```

Explanation: `/first example/ {first++}` means for each line that matches the regex pattern "first example", increment the `first` variable. `/second example/ {second++}` does the same for the second pattern. Then `END {print first second}` means at the end, it should print the two variables. Simple.

But there is one tricky thing: splitting the two numbers it prints into two different variables. You could do this with `read`:

```
bothcounts=$(awk '/first example/ {first++}; /second example/ {second++}; END {print first, second}' test.txt)
read first second <<<"$bothcounts"
```

(Note: I recommend using lower- or mixed-case variable names, to avoid conflicts with the many all-caps names that have special functions.)

Another option is to skip the `bothcounts` variable by using process substitution to feed the output from `awk` directly into `read`:

```
read first second < <(awk '/first example/ {first++}; /second example/ {second++}; END {print first, second}' test.txt)
```

Comment: This is the solution I'd use. It's funny, I was going to mention it in my answer initially but thought, "Nah, I don't want to go into how to extract two values from one command." Then my answer ballooned into a Charles Dickens novel and I forgot to circle back around and put it in.

Comment: @JohnKugelman I wondered why you hadn't covered it. BTW, thanks for the edit; I carefully found & fixed that problem, and then carefully copied & pasted the wrong version. D'oh!

Comment: i don't do stuff like this often enough to learn awk i am afraid.   and i used to use perl until the world seemed to move away from it, and i got tired of waiting for perl-6 (like waiting for republican presidential candidate tax returns)

Answer (score 0):

">" is about redirect to file/device, not to the next command in pipe. So tee will just allow you to redirect pipe to multiple files, not to multiple commands.
So just try this:

```
FIRST=$(grep 'first example' test.txt| wc --lines)
SECOND=$(grep 'second example' test.txt| wc --lines)
```

Comment: `>(command)` isn't actually redirection, it's [process substitution](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html).

Comment: ">" is redirection, and $(command) is process substitution I think, kindly correct me

Comment: `$(command)` is [command substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html). `<(command)` and `>(command)` are [process substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Process-Substitution.html). (One or both of these is poorly named, I admit.)

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to get matches an count them in a single pass, then get the count of each from the result.

```
matches="$(grep -e 'first example' -e 'second example' --only-matching test.txt | sort | uniq -c | tr -s ' ')"

FIRST=$(grep -e 'first example' <<<"$matches" | cut -d ' ' -f 2)
echo $FIRST
```

Result:

> 3

Using `awk` is the best option I think.